# event handler on dynamically added element not working with select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have done this million times before but this time it simply will not work! 
I have a function that dynamically adds a form with a link that will act as a button

```
content += '<a name="btn-opprettKontakt" id="btn-opprettKontakt" class="btn-opprettNy btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" data-action="opprettKontakt">Opprett</a>';
return content;
```

Then I have this event handler for the link

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-opprettNy', function() {
                alert('button clicked');
            });
```

The form is inside a select2 container, which is also dynamically added, so there is no parent element other than 'body'. But this never fires.

I also have an event handler for all 'button' elements that checks the data-action, which works on all other buttons. If I change this link to a button it never fires either.

Am I missing something here? .on() should work for dynamically added elements if I use an element that exists on document.ready, like 'body' , right?
Maybe the select2 container is messing things up?

I have other event handlers on dynamically added elements that work just fine.

#### UPDATE

Select2 kills all mouse events inside the dropdown. The only solution I have found so far is to use an inline onclick

Comment: Please use live instead of click

Comment: live is deprecated now.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net? Do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: hmmm. I haven't use select2. But I feel like select2 uses an iframe which has body internally. http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/16/. May be that is messing things.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your event handler! There could be a problem if you add this hyperlink multiple times because it has an id property could that be your problem?

Comment: @AlexAr I have 2 hyperlinks that are added, but they have separate id's, therefor I am using the class in the event handler.

Comment: @Abibullah Rahamathlah I have a strong feeling that the select2 is messing things up yes, but it is not an iframe. It's an div that is dynamically added to the DOM. So I am basically dynamically adding an element to a dynamically added element.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors or warnings?

Comment: There is a work around for this but it is not pretty and i prefer not to use it: you could try to subscribe newly added element right after it was added to DOM (If it doesn't work than you have some JavaScript error prior to this subscription and your code simply doesn't reach this point).

Comment: There are no erros in the console. I think it's back to the drawing bord for this one..

Comment: Hmmm..It would be better if u could provide us fiddle to find the exact cause. I also feel that snippet is just fine as @AlexAr said it already.

Comment: Here is a jfiddle that I [set up](http://jsfiddle.net/g5fhV/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 kills all mouse events inside the dropdown. 
The only solution I have found so far is to use an inline onclick

[Here](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/448) is also a solution that might help others with similar issues.